# Ideas for mutiple ajax responds for remove loading flag in complete on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this click handler which has an ajax call to get back some data and I set a flag in before send and clears it in complete. The problem that I am facing is that. When I tired to click this twice, the process goes like the following. I wondered what would be a better way to solve this issue. I thought about doing `$.active` to find out the numbers of ajax calls that's active but that doesn't seem like that right way

> 1. 1 remove initiated, set flag,
> 2. 2 remove initiated, set flag.
> 3. 1 remove response completed, reload and clear the flag.
> 4. 2 remove response completed, reload **(Since the flag was clear by the 1 response, it adds the default which I don't want )**.

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/remove'
  data: {
    fruits: $(this).val()
  },
  beforeSend: function () {
     $('#fruit-table').addClass('loading');
  }, 
  success: function (data) {
    loadFruitTable(data);
  },
  complete: function () {
    $('#fruit-table').removeClass('loading');
  }
};

loadFruitTable = function (data) {
  $('#fruit-table').html(data);
  if ($('.processing').length) {
    preLoadDefault();
  } 
};
```

Comment: You didn't close the selector here: `$('#fruit-table).addClass('loading');`

Comment: disable button while ajax in progress. Doesn't make sense to allow another load of same data before first load completes

Comment: Thank you for correcting.. that was my pseudo code.. Do you have any idea about a better way

Comment: Usually disable the button would be good but in this case there are multiple fruits in the tables which can remove.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: disable the remove button on click and enable it in the complete-part?

Comment: There are multiple of those items in the table and the issue is that the remove button is inside a booststrap popover which It would be very expensive to update all the remove button inside `data-content` for all the items in the list in ajax beforeSend, then update it again after complete

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.ajaxStart` to show the loading object and `.ajaxComplete` to handle the event of all data being loaded:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxStart handler." );
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: So I guess you are suggesting to disallow the user from doing anything while loading ?

Comment: Yes, you could use `.ajaxStart` to disallow some controls while loading is happening and enable those controls inside .ajaxComplete

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
  var $fruitTable = $('#fruit-table');

  if ($fruitTable.hasClass('loading')) {
    return;
  }

  $fruitTable.addClass('loading');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/remove'
    data: {
      fruits: $(this).val()
  })
  .then(loadFruitTable, function () {})
  .then(reinitFruitTableStatus);
};

var reinitFruitTableStatus = function () {
  $('#fruit-table').removeClass('loading');
};

loadFruitTable = function (data) {
  $('#fruit-table').html(data);
  if ($('.processing').length) {
    preLoadDefault();
  } 
};
```

If the element `#fruit-table` is not dynamically created, you should store it once in a variable available in the whole code above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... Instead of adding a class, I added a count which increments in beforeSend and decrement in complete. So that way, i can always check if there is any process that's active.